# Show that $\nabla f(a) = 0$ if and only if all directional derivatives of $f$ at the point $a$ are zero.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose we let$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function. As an example, $f(x,y) := x^3+y^3-3x^2-6y^2+3$.
How would we show that $\nabla f(a) = 0$ if and only if all directional derivatives of $f$ at the point $a$ are zero?
Thanks.

Comment: Write the directional derivative in terms of the gradient.

Comment: First of all, you could define nabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directional derivative in the direction of the unit vector $u$ is $\nabla f .u$

If $\nabla f = 0$ then $\nabla f .u=0$ for every unit vector $u$

On the other hand if directional derivative is zero at every direction it must be zero at the directiona of $ u=(1,0)$ which is $\frac {\partial f }{\partial x}$ and at direction of $(0,1)$ which is $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}$